# Change font size in verbatim and Verbatim using scaling

Tags: luatex, verbatim, typewriter, fancyvrb

This question is closely related to several other questions here, but I believe it hasn't been asked (or answered) exactly like this.

Is it possible to change the font size in `verbatim` and `Verbatim` using a scale parameter?

For example, I know I can do

`\setmonofont[Scale=0.8]{Menlo}`

to globally change `\texttt`. And from answers I've seen here I know I can change the font size in `verbatim` using

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@verbatim}
  {\verbatim@font}
  {\verbatim@font\small}
  {}{}
\makeatother
```

or adjust `Verbatim` using

```
\begin{Verbatim}[fontsize=\small]
```

But suppose I don't want to specify `\small`, but instead use a scale factor like 0.8. Can this be done? Is there also a way modify it for all `Verbatim` blocks as well?

I am using LuaLaTeX.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a command for setting the font size to a fraction of the current font size.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,xfp}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\setmonofont{Menlo}[Scale=MatchLowercase]

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\scalefont}[1]{%
  \edef\scale@fontsize{\fpeval{#1*\f@size}}%
  \edef\scale@fontbaselineskip{\fpeval{1.2*\scale@fontsize}}%
  \fontsize{\scale@fontsize}{\scale@fontbaselineskip}\selectfont
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

This is normalsize with \texttt{monospaced text}
\begin{Verbatim}[fontsize=\scalefont{0.8}]
This is scaled 80%
\end{Verbatim}
Again normalsize
\begin{Verbatim}[fontsize=\scalefont{0.5}]
This is scaled 50%
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

[image]